# javers -Compare complex JSONObject return wrong diffrences

Tags: json, javers

I have 2 complex JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonOuter1 = new JSONObject();  
JSONObject jsonOuter2= new JSONObject();  
JSONObject JsonInner1 = new JSONObject();  
JSONObject JsonInner2= new JSONObject();  
JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray();  
JSONArray arr2 = new JSONArray();  
arr1.put(new Long(12l));  
arr1.put(new String("hello"));  
arr2.put(new Long(12l));  
arr2.put(new String("hello"));  
JsonInner1.put(new String("helllo"), new Long(2l));  
JsonInner2.put(new String("helllo"), new Long(2l));  
arr1.put(JsonInner1);  
arr2.put(JsonInner2);  
jsonOuter1.put("first", arr1);  
jsonOuter2.put("first", arr2);  
Diff diff = javers.compare(jsonOuter1 , jsonOuter2);
```

Diff:

```
MapChange{globalId: org.json.JSONObject/ property: 'nameValuePairs', entryChanges: 
[EntryValueChange{ first: '[12,"hello", {"helllo":2}]'>>'[12,"hello",{"helllo":2}]' }]}
```

this is just an example, in my app i am creating those JSONObject from json records that are in the DB.
how can i compare also the inner value and get the correct result that there is no change?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

JaVers has no particular knowledge or configuration concerning org.json objects and treats them as any other objects. Before comparing your objects you should take care about domain model mapping and equals(), see https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/ 
Otherwise you get default mapping (all objects mapped as ValueObjects), which could work sometimes, but it probably won't work for complex JSON models.

It's hard to give hints about mapping org.json.JSONObject without closer look at the code.